Help reducing dynamic memory usage with LoRa library
I have combined code that reads heart rate and SPO2 then sends the data using LoRaWAN. Using these 2 libraries that work well by themselves LoraWAN lib | MAX30102 lib. My board is an Arduino Pro or Pro Mini with ATmega 328P (3.3V, 8 MHz) processor.

Global variables use 2098 bytes (102%) of dynamic memory, leaving -50 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes

I've tried reducing char array size to 8, removing some Serial.print stuff, and the best I can get is exactly 2048 bytes and getting uploaded but it won't run. Here's my Arduino code:
#include <DFRobot_MAX30102.h>
#include <lorawan.h>
DFRobot_MAX30102 particleSensor;

//ABP Credentials 
const char *devAddr = "27FD.....";
const char *nwkSKey = "9E74A99C9FE480........................";
const char *appSKey = "E2A779DC190B343.......................";

const unsigned long interval = 20000; // 10 s interval to send message
unsigned long previousMillis = 0; // will store last time message sent

char myStr[50];

const sRFM_pins RFM_pins = {
  .CS = 10,
  .RST = 9,
  .DIO0 = 2,
  .DIO1 = 6,
};

void setup() {
  //Init serial
  Serial.begin(115200);
  lora.init();
  particleSensor.begin();

  particleSensor.sensorConfiguration(/*ledBrightness=*/50, /*sampleAverage=*/SAMPLEAVG_4, \
                        /*ledMode=*/MODE_MULTILED, /*sampleRate=*/SAMPLERATE_100, \
                        /*pulseWidth=*/PULSEWIDTH_411, /*adcRange=*/ADCRANGE_16384);

  // Set LoRaWAN Class change CLASS_A or CLASS_C
  lora.setDeviceClass(CLASS_C);

  // Set Data Rate
  lora.setDataRate(SF12BW125);

  // set channel to random
  lora.setChannel(MULTI);
  
  // Put ABP Key and DevAddress here
  lora.setNwkSKey(nwkSKey);
  lora.setAppSKey(appSKey);
  lora.setDevAddr(devAddr);
}

int32_t SPO2; //SPO2
int8_t SPO2Valid; //Flag to display if SPO2 calculation is valid
int32_t heartRate; //Heart-rate
int8_t heartRateValid; //Flag to display if heart-rate calculation is valid 

void loop() {
  if(millis() - previousMillis > interval) {
    previousMillis = millis(); 
    particleSensor.heartrateAndOxygenSaturation(/**SPO2=*/&SPO2, /**SPO2Valid=*/&SPO2Valid, /**heartRate=*/&heartRate, /**heartRateValid=*/&heartRateValid);
    //Print result 
    Serial.print(heartRate, DEC);
    Serial.println(SPO2, DEC);

    sprintf(myStr, "%d,%d", heartRate,SPO2); 

    Serial.print(F("Send: "));
    Serial.println(myStr);
    
    lora.sendUplink(myStr, strlen(myStr), 0);
  }
  lora.update();
}


A replacement for sprintf() would be a step in the right direction.

i did try removing sprintf, still too much memory

Surely you don't need an int32 to store someone's heart rate.  And you don't need 50 char buffer to write two integers.

Why even store that in a buffer at all?  Just print heartRate, a space, and SPO2 in three separate prints and get rid of sprintf AND the buffer.

Also at forum.arduino.cc and getting attention there.

I’m voting to close this question because it's getting attention on another forum.

@Delta_G that is not a valid reason to close a question here

Then don't vote that way.

Find another Max30102 library, hidden in the library there are two buffers that took up 800 bytes memory.

Judging from the source code, your sketch does not look RAM-heavy at
all. The high RAM usage almost certainly comes from the libraries you
are using. Other than using different libraries, or a different board,
you don't have much leverage here.
On the sketch itself, the only thing that sticks out is the myStr
array, which you could make much smaller. Other than that, I suggest
moving the constant strings devAddr, nwkSKey and appSKey to
PROGMEM, and copying them to RAM only when needed:
const char devAddr[] PROGMEM = "27FD.....";
// and so on for nwkSKey and appSKey

void setup() {
    // ...
    char buffer[39];  // RAM buffer for nwkSKey, appSKey and devAddr
    memcpy_P(buffer, nwkSKey, sizeof nwkSKey);
    lora.setNwkSKey(nwkSKey);
    memcpy_P(buffer, appSKey, sizeof appSKey);
    lora.setAppSKey(appSKey);
    memcpy_P(buffer, devAddr, sizeof devAddr);
    lora.setDevAddr(devAddr);
}

This way the three strings share the same RAM space, which is freed as
soon as setup() returns.
Other than that, you may try sending the data in binary instead of
ASCII. I am not sure this would save much RAM though:
void loop() {
    // ...
    struct {
        int32_t heartRate;
        int32_t SPO2;
    } loraPacket;
    char dummy;
    particleSensor.heartrateAndOxygenSaturation(
            /** SPO2 = */         &loraPacket.SPO2,
            /** SPO2Valid = */    &dummy,
            /** heartRate = */    &loraPacket.heartRate,
            /** heartRateValid=*/ &dummy);
    lora.sendUplink(loraPacket, strlen(loraPacket), 0);
}

This would let you remove the myStr variable, at the cost of having to
change the receiver's code, and making the communication protocol harder
to read.
Edit: If you don't mind modifying the DFRobot_MAX30102 library, you
may save 184 bytes of RAM by storing uch_spo2_table in PROGMEM:
// In src/SPO2/algorithm.h, add PROGMEM:
const uint8_t uch_spo2_table[184] PROGMEM = {/* ... */ };

// In src/SPO2/algorithm.h, line 199, add pgm_read_byte():
n_spo2_calc = pgm_read_byte(&uch_spo2_table[n_ratio_average]);

